# Simple email form giving 405 HTTP verb error on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, html, forms, iis

I'm trying to set up a suggestion box form that emails a suggestion.
This page is on an internal IIS server.
When I select Submit, the server returns a 405 error:
Server Error
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Here is the html:

```
<body>

<!-- Start code for the form-->
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Enter Name: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='email'>Enter Email Address:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for='message'>Enter Message:</label> <br>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Here is the php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'internal@domain.com';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "internal@domain.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm a novice and only know that it may be a server configuration or path syntax issue.

Comment: I think your line `done. redirect to thank-you page.` should be a comment

Comment: Yes.  It is in the actual code.  I missed it when I copied to this post.  Still errors out.

Comment: From what I am gathering, it is hitting an error right when it hits the php file.

Comment: I set up a dead-simple html file with basic php in it. The html code works but no php echo displayed.
`code`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>`code`

Comment: I am closer!  I added FastCGI and PHP to the IIS server.  Now there are no errors, I'm just not getting any emails.  :(